# send message from mobile and receive by server

Tags: networking, mobile

There are many applications/sites which allow us to send message(SMS) to mobile. Is the reverse of it - send SMS by mobile and receive/get that into server(some user account), is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Take a look at Twilio. They have a really good API for doing this.

http://www.twilio.com/

Comment: Twillio seems really good... but it is providing service to only US and Canada....